# Imported module as a class or instance method?

Tags: python, dependency-injection

Is it fine to make a module an instance method or probaby class method so that child classes need not import them again if it is in another file and you can easily over-ride them? Also is class or instance method preferred here?

```
import submodule

class MyClass(object):


    def __init__(self):
        """
        """
        pass

    def mysubmodule():
        """
        Method that returns the submodule.
        """
        return submobdule
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the child class is defined in the same file, there will be no need for a second import.

If the child class is defined in a different file, I fail to see the advantage of your idea. Add the import and every reader of the child class knows what the code is using.

Comment: Yeah, we mostly over-ride it in a different file.